# Adding a 'Ready for Sale' version to Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

Can I use 'Ready for Sale' version for Testflight?
Can I use a lower version of a 'Ready for Sale' for the Testflight? 
Or do I need to upload a version greater than the 'Ready for Sale' version?

Answer (score 2):

Test Flight is for testing a new version that isn't yet in the App Store. The version marked as "Ready for Sale" is in the App Store so there is no reason to test that version. And there is even less reason to test an earlier version.

Update your app with the new changes you wish to test, do a build with an updated version (build number) and submit to iTunes Connect. Then you can add that new version to Test Flight for testing. Repeat until the test version is acceptable then submit that version for review.

tl;dr - You need to upload a version greater than "Ready for Sale" for testing.